# Is it possible to use QML and QtQuick without QApplication?

Tags: c++, qt, audio, qml, vst

I am looking for a way to write an audio plugin using Qt. Audio plugins usually are dynamic libraries, not applications (http://teragonaudio.com/article/How-to-make-VST-plugins-in-Visual-Studio.html). While searching, I found on the audio forum contains the post [QT etc for vst UI](https://www.kvraudio.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=448562):

> QtQuick/QML is perfect for any GUI development, including plugins. The
> only downside is that the payload is big (size of deployment). But
> that's really just the installation size and none of it affects
> performance. There are numerous ways to inject QtQuick scene graph to
> a window and not all of them are tied to or limited by the
> QApplication fake singleton. Gluing generic C++/Boost to Qml is made
> simple and thread-safe and Qt Quick scene graph itself runs mostly on
> GPU.
>
> It's really just best to avoid all the QApplication and old Qt
> graphics framework techniques. They were good for maybe KDE and
> embedded systems (dentists chairs) ten years a go. QML made all that
> obsolete. For KDE also by the way.

Are these statements correct?
How can one use Qml and Qt Quck without `QApplication` in a c++ project? Can I use `qtbase` module in such a project?

Comment: Start with the fact, that QQuickItem is a subclass of QObject and QObject needs an event loop to function properly. _QGuiApplication contains the main event loop, where all events from the window system and other sources are processed and dispatched._

Comment: You should write your plugin such that during it's life-time there is a QApplication/QGuiApplication that you instantiated yourself

Comment: I have used the VST SDK to write plugins aprox. 20 years ago. Could you please tell how the plugin is instantiated by the host in VST3?

Comment: @scopchanov Host app loads VST3 plugin as a dynamic library, which should implement some interface.

Comment: @scopchanov you can see it in the JUCE source file https://github.com/juce-framework/JUCE/blob/master/modules/juce_audio_processors/format_types/juce_VST3PluginFormat.cpp  by looking at the methods containing the "factory" in the name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read through all the posts in your link and I think the author was being very loose with his terms. When he says:

> It's really just best to avoid all the QApplication and old Qt graphics framework techniques.

He appears to simply be referring to avoiding Qt Widgets. The [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html) say "QApplication specializes QGuiApplication with some functionality needed for QWidget-based applications." In another post, he points to a QQuickRenderControl example, which he doesn't provide a link to, but I assume is [this](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtdeclarative.git/tree/examples/quick/rendercontrol). That example uses QML along with a QGuiApplication, just not a QApplication.

Qt has examples for creating plugins for Qt-based applications. If you're wanting to use Qt to create a plugin for a non-Qt application, then it might work, but be prepared to have to ship the Qt libraries with your plugin, and you probably will still need a QGuiApplication. I don't really see a way around that.